# How to Custom User model inherit and serialize them in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `ProDetails` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `CustomUser` instance.
Original exception text was: `CustomUser` object has no attribute `ProDetails`.

## Models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username=None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_shopCreated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
```

```
class ProDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    profileimage = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='photos', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    coverImg =  models.ImageField(
        upload_to='photos', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

## Serializer.py

```
class ProDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProDetails
        fields = ['id','pincode']

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ProDetails = ProDetailsSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'created_at', 'ProDetails']
```

## View.py

```
class profiledata(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    authentication_classes = [
        JWTAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = CustomUser.objects.all()
        return user

    def get(self, request, id=None):
       if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
       else:
            item = self.list(request)
            return item
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to retrieve `foreign key` information while using `SerializerModel` you have to define the `related_name` of the foreign key as serializer field. so here you have not defined `related_nane` for `CustomerUser` in the `ProDetails model`. So by default, Django sets the related name as `prodetails_set`. To fix your issue you have to define the related name as the field name for `ProDetailsSerializer` in `UserSerializer`. after this change your serializer will look like this

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    prodetails_set = ProDetailsSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'created_at', 'prodetails_set']
```